# I am trying to make a rank card using PIL and discord.py UPDATED

Tags: discord.py, python-imaging-library

i have a leveling system, using discord.py, i am trying to make a rank card, like mee6 and arcane. i wanna get the image to display the users rank and xp

heres the command that works, but i want to make it into a image.

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

and heres my crappy atempt.

```
@bot.command()
async def text(ctx):

    text = [f"level {lvl}, exp {exp}"]
    user = ctx.message.author
    img = Image.open("rank.jpg")
    with open('level.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
    exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
    text = ['Level {}'.format(lvl)]

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", 150)

    draw.text((480,445), text, (0, 0, 0,), font=font)

    img.save("rankcard.jpg")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("rankcard.jpg"))
```

and heres the console error, i doubt theres only one error with my code

```
Ignoring exception in command text:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\just some code\bot.py", line 33, in text
    text = [f"level {lvl}, exp {exp}"]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lvl' referenced before assignment

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lvl' referenced before assignment
```

if you could fix up the code for me. i would be ever so greatful.
-thanks

UPDATE: i have now sorted those issues out but still trying to figure this out, my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    global lvl, exp

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
    img = Image.open("rank.jpg")
    lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
    exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
    text = [f"level {lvl}, exp {exp}"]

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", 150)

    draw.text((480,445), text, (0, 0, 0,), font=font)

    img.save("rankcard.jpg")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("rankcard.jpg"))
```

and my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: expected string
```

Comment: Define `text` after getting lvl and xp values from json file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to firstly define `lvl` and `exp` in the text function or `global` it as this is not found.

```py
@bot.command()
async def text(ctx):
    lvl = ...
    exp = ...

    text = [f"level {lvl}, exp {exp}"]
    user = ctx.message.author
```

OR

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    global lvl, exp

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
```

Comment: i have edited the thing but its still not working. please check my origonal question